# Firebase Push Key

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want to insert an ID with firebase push key as value..
[image]

this is the code:

```
chatRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('childname');
Map<String, String> data = { 'id': chatRef.push().key}
chatRef.push().set(data);
```

but when i use ...push().key; it returns other digits..
can you help me what should i do to have value of ID have the same value as the push key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the child with that defined key. It should look like this:

```
DatabaseReference chatRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference(); 
String key = chatRef.child('childname').push().key;
chatRef.child('childname').child(key).set(<String, String>{'id': key,});
```

Comment: Thank you! it works.. i thought the key is generate randomly so we cant set the push key